# Ref displaying a question mark instead of the equation number

Tags: equations

I labelled two equations in the align environment but when I reference them it shows only the second equation's number, the reference for the first one shows a question mark instead

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,}


    \begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{align}
    &x^2+y^2 = |Z|\\ \label{Eq1}
    &x^2-y^2 = Re(Z) \label{Eq2}
    \end{align}
    \ref{Eq1} \ref{Eq2}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This code throws an error: *never* ignore errors. The first `\label` should come *before* ``\\``.

Comment: apart from the error with `\label` the alignment seems wrong you are not specifying any alignment points other than the left edge. the `&` is usually placed before the `=` use `gather` if you want unaligned equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{align} 
 \label{Eq1}
 x^2+y^2 = |Z|\\
 \label{Eq2}
  x^2-y^2 = Re(Z) 
  \end{align}
  \ref{Eq1} \ref{Eq2} 
  \end{document}
```